# Finding a function where $\lim_{x \to a}|f(x)| = |L|$, but $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \ne L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find a function such that $\lim_{x \to a}|f(x)| = |L|$, but $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \ne L$. I came up with this:

$f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is a positive or negative even number

$f(x) = -1$ otherwise.

Then, $|f(x)| = 1 \, \forall x$. Put $a=0$. Then, $\lim_{x \to 0}|f(x)| =1$ , but $\lim_{x \to 0}|f(x)| =-1$ and we are done. I am not sure if this example is correct. If we look at the contrapositive of the statement:

$\lim_{x \to a}|f(x)| = |L|$, but $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) \ne L$

the example fails because $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = -1$ (which implies $L=-1$) and $\lim_{x \to 0} |f(x)| = 1 = |L|$. Is this example correct?

Comment: Also, you seem to have a typo: "... but $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)|=-1$", it should be $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=-1$

Comment: What do you mean when you say $|L|$ in the first sentence? What is $L$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your solution is not completely correct, but you are on the right track. Try $f(x)=x/|x|$ and $a=0$ instead.

Actually, even simpler would be $f(x)=-1$, $L=1$, any $a$.  Are you sure the problem is stated correctly? Is $L$ given?

Comment: No, $L$ is not given. $|L|$ is what $|f(x)|$ approaches as $x \to a$. Sorry, but I don't think the $f(x) = -1$ example works.If we take $a=1$, then $|f(x)| \to 1$ which implies that $|L| = 1 \implies L \in \{1, -1\}$. And, $a=1$, $f(x) \to -1$ which can equal $|L|$. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I have chosen $L=1$, and $\lim_{x\to a} |f(x)| = 1 = |L|$ but $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = -1 \not= 1 = L$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually any non-zero constant function works. For example, let $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be the constant function $f(x) =1$. Take $a=0, L=-1$. Then, $\lim_{x\to 0}|f(x)| = 1 = |L|$, but clearly $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) =1 \neq -1 = L$.

Comment: With $f(x) = 1$, as $a \to 0, f(x) \to 1$, so $L \ne -1$. Instead, $L =1$.

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson the limit of $f(x)$ is $1$ yes, but I'm telling you to define $L=-1$. This way, $f(x)$ and $|f(x)|$ both approach the same limit of $1 = |-1| = |L|$, but of course $|L| \neq L$ in this case.